# Options from external commands in vim?

Tags: command-line, file-operations

If I run from the vim terminal

```
:! zathura foo.pdf
```

It opens foo on top of the terminal and when I exit I go back to the vim file. If instead I try:

```
:! zathura --fork foo.pdf
```

The intended behaviour is to open the pdf in a new window while still having the vim file open. It doesn't open at all. What do I do to fix this and why is it occuring?

Comment: `The intended behaviour is to open the pdf in a new window` - are you using tiling window manager?

Comment: I'm using dwm. This is what happens when I run the command on a new terminal.

Comment: I get the expected behavior with `--fork`: I can get back to Vim and see the pdf in zathura at the same time. Can you double check if your version of zathura has the `--fork` option? If you try `zathura --fork foo.pdf` in a normal shell, does it work correctly?

Answer (score -2):

I got the solution:

```
:! st zathura food.pdf
```

Comment: Can you please try to improve your answer, perhaps by explaining why this helps in your case (assuming you understand that), or what in your environment makes it work for you (dwm window manager? st terminal?) Can you explain how you got to the conclusion that this is what was missing?